# the simplest way to use external HTML file as HTML code without JavaScript

Tags: html

Is there a simple way to include HTML code, stored as a text file or HTML file, into my main HTML?

I've seen multiple technique on internet, but they always use JavaScript.
In my case all the files are stored on a NAS to access it locally (like : http://ip.of.the.nas/mypage.html).

And so, JavaScript based solution, doesn't work in my case.

I need something like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>

      <p>my main content</p>

      <div magic-function-to-include = "someCode.html" ></div>

    </body>
  </html>
```

So how can I do something like this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Even if your files are stored on a NAS, JavaScript still works within the browser, when opening your files. So why does "it not work in your case"?

Comment: So, understanding why JavaScript doesn't work in my case is maybe the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you convert your page from html to php.
And you can use:
require or include function.

```
<?php
    include("someCode.html");

    require("someCode.html");
?>
```

You can use into a div or body.